# Finding all complex roots of $z^{11}+z=1$ with $|z|=1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> Find all complex roots of $z^{11}+z=1$ with $|z|=1$.

I have factored the equation into $$(z^2-z+1)(z^9+z^8-z^6-z^5+z^3+z^2-1)=0$$ and found the roots to the first part: ${1\over 2} + {i\sqrt{3}\over 2}$ and ${1\over 2} - {i\sqrt{3}\over 2}$ but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Could you share some more information with us like why are you asking the question or where is the task coming from? This might be helpful when writing replies.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf (especially Theorem 1.1 on page 2)

Comment: Hint: $\;z^{11} + z = 1 = \bar z^{11} + \bar z\,$. When $\,|z|=1\,$, $\,\bar z = \ldots$

Comment: Alternate hint. Triangle with sides $-1,z,z^{11}$ has lengths 1, so equilateral, so angle between -1 and $z$ is $120$ degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Since $z^{10}+1 ={1\over z}$ we have $$|z^{10}+1 | = 1$$ so $z^{10}$ is on circle with center at $-1$ and radius $1$. But $z^{10}$ is also on a circle with center at $0$ and radius $1$. So $$z^{10} = \cos {2\pi \over 3}\pm i\sin {2\pi \over 3}$$
and now should be easy...